# Is there any way to set ng-grid row height at run time?

Tags: angularjs

I want to set rowHeight property of grid at run time? My requirement is not like different height for different rows, but same height for all the rows but that can be set at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You could set row Height from grid options which will set height of row at rendering time of grid.

**Code**

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
    ...
    rowHeight: 35, //<-- you can set height 
    ...
  };
```